# Toggle right click menu on button click - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Following is my jQuery Code which is working fine except for the first click. I am expecting the right click to be disabled on the first click, but somehow first click is not disabling the right click but after that toggle works. Let me know what I am doing wrong here.

**jQuery Code -**

```
let $document = $(document);
    $document.ready(() => {
        let toggleValue = true;
        $('.btn-toggle').on('click', () => {
            $document.on('contextmenu', (e) => {
                if(toggleValue) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
            });
        toggleValue = !toggleValue;
    })
})
```

**HTML Code -**

```
<h3>Toggle right click menu on button click</h3>

<button class="btn-toggle">Toggle Right Click</button>
```

**JSFIDDLE -** https://jsfiddle.net/mLm096o4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the code to handle right clicks from within event listener for the *Toggle Right Click* button.

```
const $document = $(document);

$document.ready(() => {
  let toggleValue;

  $('.btn-toggle').on('click', () => {
    toggleValue = !toggleValue;
  });

  $document.on('contextmenu', (e) => {
    if (toggleValue) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  });
});
```

Also, you can change `let $document = $(document);` to `const $document = $(document);` as you won't be assigning a different value to this variable (at least you shouldn't be).

**Edit**: updated in response to comment.

Comment: This will make the right click disabled by default. I want it to be disable/enable by button click

Comment: Just change the `let toggleValue = true;` to `let toggleValue;`. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You reassign click handlers over and over - try assign the click handler just once.

```
let $document = $(document);        
    $document.ready(() => {
        let toggleValue = true;
        $document.on('contextmenu', (e) => {
                if(toggleValue) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
            });

        $('.btn-toggle').on('click', () => {            
            toggleValue = !toggleValue;
        })
    })
```

Comment: This will make the right click disabled by default. I want it to be disable/enable by button click

Comment: Start with `let toggleValue = false` then.

Answer (score 0):

simply use `if(toggleValue === false)` instead of `if(toggleValue)`

```js
let $document = $(document);  
$document.ready(() => {
  let toggleValue = true;
  $('.btn-toggle').on('click', () => {
    $document.on('contextmenu', (e) => {
      if(toggleValue === false) {
        e.preventDefault();
      }
    });
    toggleValue = !toggleValue;
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>Toggle right click menu on button click</h3>

<button class="btn-toggle">Toggle Right Click</button>
```

Comment: As Evan points out, with this solution, you are assigning click handlers over and over...